# how do we use "while" and "than"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

There is one sentence that goes like this:

> How will we handle one-on-one instruction while social distancing?

I think the sentence should go like this:

> How will we handle one-on-one instruction while we keep social distancing?

Another sentence is:

> I would rather choose remote learning than the dead.

I think it should be:

> I would rather choose remote learning than death.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`How will we handle one-on-one instruction while social distancing?`

This sentence uses "social distance" as a verb, which is a neologism, a new usage. It is awkward, and probably best avoided. A more usual construction would be "while distancing socially". The phrases "social distance" and "social distancing" appear in dictionaries, but as nouns, not verbs.
[Cambridge "social distancing"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/social-distancing)
"the practice of keeping away from other people as much as possible, or of keeping a certain distance from other people, in order to stop a disease from spreading to a lot of people:
*To slow the transmission, social distancing might be useful.*
*The cities that instigated early social distancing measures did better.*"

Your suggested revision, "while we keep social distancing" is ambiguous as to whether "social distancing" is a noun or a verb, because "keep" can be used with a verb to mean "continue", for example, "try to keep talking". So, that revision isn't much of an improvement.
If you say "while we maintain social distancing", then "social distancing" is clearly a noun, and that would be a reasonable way to rewrite the original.

The second sentence you ask about,
`I would rather choose remote learning than the dead.`
That sentence doesn't make sense, and I wonder where you got it. Your revision makes sense.